# NPE at animation when setting the dots for a FlipperView

Tags: android, animation, nullpointerexception, viewflipper

I have a very simple activity (One.class) in which I am showcasing a ViewFlipper + a LinearLayout where I am installing some dots that show the progress in the shift of the views (some RelativeLayout actually).

```
public class One extends Activity {

private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
private float lastX;
private LinearLayout mDotsLayout;
private int mDotsCount;
static ImageView Points[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);

    mDotsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.image_count);

    mDotsCount = viewFlipper.getChildCount();

    Points = new ImageView[mDotsCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < mDotsCount; i++) {
        Points[i] = new ImageView(this);
        Points[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.hide);
        mDotsLayout.addView(Points[i]);
    }

    One.Points[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.clip);


    viewFlipper.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            int displayed = viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();

            System.out.println("zoot >" + displayed + " Count >" + viewFlipper.getChildCount());

            for (int i = 0; i < mDotsCount; i++) {
                One.Points[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.hide);
            }

            One.Points[displayed].setImageResource(R.drawable.clip);

        }
    });



}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
{
    switch (touchevent.getAction())
    {
        // when user first touches the screen to swap
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            lastX = touchevent.getX();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            float currentX = touchevent.getX();

            // if left to right swipe on screen
            if (lastX < currentX)
            {
                // If no more View/Child to flip
                if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                    break;

                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
                // Show the next Screen
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            }

            if (lastX > currentX)
            {
                if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                    break;

                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Here comes the problem: when I set the animation to move the images, I receive a NPE related to the row "*viewFlipper.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {*".
My first guess is that it's due to the fact that I have set an animation listener elsewhere to set the animation when shifting view.
Any further idea?

The Logcat highlights are :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: xxxxxx, PID: 31808
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxxxx.One}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime:     at xxxxxx.One.onCreate(One.java:64)
```

I have correctly set the android:inAnimation and the android:outAnimation
what else could it be??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to state the obvious, but either the viewFlipper is null (which mean it could not find view by that id, maybe spelling error?) or that view has no animation, causing getAnimation() returns null. I would stop the debugger on that line and see which is it. Should be fairly straightforward one you know which one.

Since you are setting an animation in the onTouch method, my guess is that the viewFlipper has no other animation so when you create the activity (there is yet no onTouch event) the getAnimation returns null. Maybe you want to set the animations before adding the listener?

Comment: Found!
Somehow, copy+paste did not work, it forgot a "in" in the statement   viewFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {     FML